# Why does this user's SMTP-AUTH e-mails vanish when sent to some groups?

Tags: exchange-2013

I've got a user "Bob" with an interesting problem.  He needs to send to the distribution group "group", but has a problem with the e-mails just vanishing.  From the client (SMTP-AUTH w/TLS on the MSA port) standpoint, it's successful.  Bob authenticates and the Exchange server accepts the e-mails.  However, the Exchange server then fails to deliver them (tracing the message shows a "FAIL" in the "ROUTING", have not been able to get anything more detailed than that so far).  Seems simple enough, but it gets more interesting when testing variations:

- Bob can send to any *individual* user on Exchange just fine through SMTP-AUTH.
- Bob can send to the group fine through the Exchange *webmail* interface.
- Bob can send to several *other* groups fine through SMTP-AUTH.
- Any *new* groups I add (for testing), Bob cannot send to through SMTP-AUTH, failing silently just as above (but works fine through webmail).
- If I swap my credentials into the program in place of Bob's, it sends fine to the group.
- If I create a new user (for testing) and use those credentials, it fails to send to the group with an authentication error returned to the client, but sends to individuals fine!

I'm kind of at a loss here, it's such a specific set of circumstances that I can't even think of a mechanism in the server that could cause it.  Sounds permissions related somehow, but why would one submission form succeed when another fails for only these very specific cases?